# Weighted joint probability

Tags: probability

I need to solve a joint probability:
$$ P(x_1, x_2, ...x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N(1- p(x_i))$$ 
but all the variables have different importance level. I have a weight $\sigma _i$ to measure the relative importance of every variable $x_i$. I want to solve something like
$$ P'(x_1, x_2, ...x_N) = \prod_{i=1}^N (1 -\sigma _i p(x_i))$$ 
but I think this is not a probability anymore. Is there any rigorous way of doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: Your $P'$ idea is useless because that's just a scaling $P' = k\cdot P$ with $k = \prod_i \sigma_i$ of the joint PDF. You would need an exponentiation I guess.

Comment: Way to screw with helpful people with late changes of key aspects of your question ...

Comment: I'm sorry I made a mistake

Answer (score 3):

You can always use

$$P_\text{norm}(x_1...x_N) 
= \frac{P'(x_1\ldots x_n)}{\int_{x_1\ldots x_n} P'(x_1\ldots x_n) dx_1\ldots dx_n}$$

to normalize your creation. I am still not convinced of your weighting method making much sense though, maybe try exponents and play around with the weights in a program like Matlab.

EDIT: Yup, exponents seem to be more fruitful: http://new.sis-statistica.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/RS12-Weighted-likelihood-in-Bayesian-inference.pdf